# Problem about Proposition

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying real analysis I, and I found one proposition does not make sense for me.

Proposition: Let $\sum a_n$, be a series ,($n\geq m$), of non negative real numbers. Then this series is convergent iff there is a real number $M$ such that

$∑_{n=m}^Na_n\leq M, (N\geq m).$

OK.
We know that $(\sum 1/n)$ diverges.
Now let us take $N=1000$
so$ ∑(1/n)=7.99$
We can clearly find $M$ in $R$ such that $7.99\leq M.$ 
And so for all $N$ we can find $M$ such that $∑_{n=m}^Na_n\leq M,$  , and therefore by this proposition $∑(1/n)$ converges which contradicts the fact!!!

I appreciate any clarification with this problem.

Comment: Where does $∑\frac 1n =7.99$ come from?

Comment: No, you can't do that for all $N$, because the series diverges when you let $N$ tend to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n\ge m}a_n$ converges if and only if

> there exists $M$ such that, for every $N\ge m$,
>   $$
> \sum_{n=m}^N a_n\le M
> $$

This $M$ should not depend on $N$.

Note that

> for all $N\ge m$ there exists $M$ such that
>   $$
> \sum_{n=m}^N a_n\le M
> $$

is a completely different statement, which is trivially satisfied for every series, convergent or not. You have the order of the quantifier (“there exists” and “for all”) reversed.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of why your logic doesn't work, consider any series where the terms are finite. Your logic would dictate that on the basis that you can take a partial sum for that series and then pick some arbitrary number bigger than that (I suggest Graham's, it'll work in *most* cases), the series doesn't diverge.

Can you see where your logic is wrong?